# Still getting “ssh failure: Offending RSA key in /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts” despite removing the specified key from “known_hosts”

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but there's a difference here:

Trying to ssh to the server I get:

```
$ ssh cl11lx
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
07:51:03:4e:5e:ba:e8:44:70:77:cb:57:78:57:59:35.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /nethome/ajalali/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts:8
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts" -R cl11lx
ECDSA host key for cl11lx has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

The most relevant question I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840012/ssh-remote-host-identification-has-changed), which is closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654064/ubuntu-ssh-warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed) which itself is closed as off-topic. But they're not the same anyway. Another related question is asked [here](http://osdir.com/ml/freeipa-users/2015-06/msg00204.html).

In most cases, as we know, you can fix the problem by replacing the server key, for example by running:

```
ssh-keygen -R <host>
```

But neither this solution, nor removing the offending key from the file `/var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts` did solve my problem.

As soon as I remove that whole file, or remove the offending key, the key is back.

Please note that all my systems are members of a freeipa server, which itself is an LDAP/Kerberos on the backend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As seen in the posted log, the offending key is not in its normal place, i.e. `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`, but it's rather located in `/var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts`. This suggests that **System Security Services Daemon** aka **sssd** is fetching the offending key from another source.

This is why removing the key from the file has no effect, because it's being re-fetched from a server over and over again.

In this case, the server is a FreeIPA server. Therefore to fix the problem, the offending key sent by the IPA server has to be changed.

This can be done by manually changing the key on the server, or removing the host information from the server completely, and installing the client (via `ipa-client-install`) again.

My problem happened after re-installing the OS on the client. Therefore it is a sensible option for me to remove the host info from the server and install the IPA client again.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: On the server you want to connect to, run:

```
ipa host-mod --sshpubkey="`cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`" --sshpubkey="`cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`" --sshpubkey="`cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`"  `hostname`
```

What's happening here is that the ssh client is retrieving the server host's public key from the IPA Server, but the IPA Server doesn't know that the host's public key has changed.

ssh gets the old key, and ssh becomes unhappy.

To update the keys in the IPA server, use `ipa host-mod` or the IPA WebGUI.

If you only need ed25519, it's fine to skip the other keys. E.g:

```
ipa host-mod --sshpubkey="`cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`" `hostname`
```

Using the WebGUI requires more cut and paste to add keys, so depending on what you want to do, the command line may be the easier option.

If you want to view or modify ssh keys using the WebGUI:

1. navigate to `Hosts`->'your host'->`Settings`
2. scroll down to `SSH Keys`
3. view or update using the `show/set`, `delete` and `add` buttons
4. scroll up and `save`

If you want some ways to get the key without logging in to the target host, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126908/get-ssh-server-key-fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

The issue is created by sssd.
Instead of re-installing freeipa, I did the below work-around:

Temporarily backup /var/lib/sss/pubconf /var/lib/sss/pubconf_bkp

ssh again to the remote machine. This will update the new hostkey.

Move back /var/lib/sss/pubconf_bkp to /var/lib/sss/pubconf

Now try again. The issue will not recur.

Note: Don't forget to move back /var/lib/sss/pubconf, else LDAP authentication will fail

Answer (score 0):

1st delete the host keys from the file showing the error. In my case it is /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts. Then regenerate from the source and push to ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Delete keys from the file:

```
ssh-keygen -R <host name or IP for which getting error> -f /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts

ssh-keygen -R <host name or IP for which getting error> -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Generate from the source and push to ~/.ssh/known_hosts

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa <host name or IP for which getting error> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```